# Collecting varnish stats at the Url Level

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

We are using varnish to cache different urls like:-

- `/discovery/v1/search`
- `/discovery/v1/suggest`
- `/discovery/v1/recommend`
- `/orders/ordersearch`

Right now we were able to get varnish stats like `cache_hit`, `cache_miss` for the overall varnish. Is there a way we can get the stats at the url level like `cache_hit`, `cache_miss`, etc for `/discovery/v1/search`, `/discovery/v1/suggest`  separately?

Environment:-

- varnishd (varnish-4.1.0 revision 3041728)
- Debian 8 (x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run varnishncsa if you are not already. Add this parameter to the DAEMON_OPTS (or command line arguments) for the format:

```
%{Varnish:handling}x
```

I changed the following single line in the init.d script for varnishncsa like this:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a -w $logfile -D -P $pidfile -F \"%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %D %{VCL_Log:Referer}x [%{X-Forwarded-For}i] %{Varnish:handling}x\""
```

This will give you "hit", "miss" or "pass" in the handling field for each line.

Then I would post process the log-file when logrotated runs.